# Number called using empty string, null, or undefined

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

The following calls returns value of 0:

```
var n1 = Number()         // n1 === 0 is true
var n2 = Number("")       // n2 === 0 is true
var n3 = Number(null)     // n3 === 0 is true
```

I tried above in Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.119

But, is this behavior well-defined?  I'm not sure if it behaves the same way in other browsers.

Comment: It's defined in the `ToNumber()` internal operation description in the language spec.

Comment: Look at the spec https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-numbers-and-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-numbers-and-dates)

[image]

For string-to-number conversion, there is added information in the next section: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is an expected behavior on all the browsers.

Any non executable value passed to constructor of Number will return 0.

```
var num1 = Number();
var num2 = Number("");
var num3 = Number(false);
var num4 = Number(null);
// here num1, num2, num3 and num4 will be 0 as undefined, empty string, false and null are non-executable values.
```

If you pass executable non-number value to constructor of Number, it will return NaN

```
var num5 = Number("abc");
var num6 = Number({});
var num7 = Number([]);
// num5, num6 and num7 will be NaN as non-empty string, any object and any array are executable but Not a number values.
```

Answer (score -2):

When no argument is provided Number() will always return 0 and if the argument is illegale so Number() will return NaN